# Prevent frontmatter to reset counting

Tags: numbering, front-matter

I would like to keep the same numbering throughout the whole document. But `frontmatter` and `mainmatter` are resetting the numbering. How can I prevent this behaviour?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}     
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
Some text here.
\mainmatter
\chapter{chapter1}
\chapter{chapter2}
\chapter{chapter3}
\chapter{chapter4}
\backmatter
\chapter{annexe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: doing a clearpage and resetting the numbering is the main thing that \frontmatter and \mainmatter do, you do not have to use them at all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting an (almost) working minimal document. I've edited your question to make the document compilable. For this particular question it wasn't crucial, but for future questions it's really helpful to make sure that you include a compilable minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to redefine the commands: add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\frontmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  %\pagenumbering{roman}% Don't reset
}
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  %\pagenumbering{arabic}% Don't reset
}
\makeatother
```

before `\begin{document}`.

As you see, redefining `\pagenumbering` to do nothing, as suggested in another answer, would work. But maybe somebody could ask you to number differently the appendix…

Answer (score 0):

The markup commands `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` use `\pagenumbering` to change the number style and reset the page number. It can be redefined to do nothing:

```
\renewcommand*{\pagenumbering}[1]{}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the roman vs. arabic numbering that `\frontmatter` and  `\mainmatter` implement, then you can do the following.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mainmatter{
    \@mainmattertrue\cleardoublepage\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}}
\makeatother
```

If you want arabic numbering throughout, then egreg's answer works fine.